# nested loop wordpress without duplicate post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to loop which will show total 16 diffirence posts,it will divide to 4x.The seconds x4 loop will show 1 post each , total 4 posts in 1. Post not duplicate! Plz help me ty!

```
<div class="slide-start fl col-lg-12 clear">
    <!-- start 1st loop here, big loop to get totals 16 posts -->
        <div class="groupitem">
            <!-- start 2nd loop here to get 4 posts -->
            <div class="g-item fl">
                <a class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-img" href=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?></a>
                <a class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-tit" href=""><?php the_title() ;?></a>
                <span class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-type">Hair</span>
                <p class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-price"><span>105</span> USD <span>(0.5</span> KG)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/array_chunk) and [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) are what you need.

Comment: Hi Darren! May you make a demo code? Tks

Comment: `$chunks = array_chunk($data, 4); foreach($chunks as $chunk) { foreach($chunk as $item) { /*echo everything you need.*/ }}`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 16);
$posts = get_posts($args);
$rows = array_chunk($posts, 4);
?>
<div class="slide-start fl col-lg-12 clear">
  <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <div class="groupitem">
        <?php foreach($row as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <div class="g-item fl">
              <a class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-img" href=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?></a>
              <a class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-tit" href=""><?php the_title() ;?></a>
              <span class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-type">Hair</span>
              <p class="fl clear col-lg-12 pro-price"><span>105</span> USD <span>(0.5</span> KG)</p>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```